# Unable to run model_main.py for training data. contrib error

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, object-detection

System information

Windows 10
TensorFlow version 2.0.0
Python 3.6.9 in virtual environment
CUDA/cuDNN: Yes
GPU model and memory: GTX1080Ti, 11GB

I've tried to run `python main_model.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config`

but unable to do so due to Attribute error. heres the error shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main.py", line 26, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\model_lib.py", line 27, in <module>
    from object_detection import eval_util
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\eval_util.py", line 40, in <module>
    slim = tf.contrib.slim
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

i have done some research on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33442 
and the best i can get is told to find alternative using this link : https://github.com/tensorflow/addons

to be honest i'm still new to this and don't know what to replace the contrib in tensorflow 2.0.0

i'm currently following the tutorial from https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10

actual result should be able to train data without error

Comment: as per https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33442 it seem contrib has been removed from latest TF-2.0 version. Anyone know any other workaround other that reverting to previous version of TF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all the projects in `tf.contrib` were not officially supported by Tensorflow and it had designated owners for maintaining it.
All the contributions and features were meant to merge into core Tensorflow.

From the Tensorflow 2.0 version all the `contrib` projects had one of three options for its future: `move to core`; `move to a separate repository`; or delete, most of which have been reviewed with the respective project owners.

This [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md#list-of-projects) provides the details and status for all the projects under `tf.contrib`.

If the library you are using is moved to the core or separate repository, the TensorFlow's automatic code migration from 1.x to 2.x will not work for `tf.contrib projects`. You need to change your code manually for these parts, which is suggested going forward.

Hope this answers your question, Happy Learning!